# Solving $-1\leq \frac{-k \pm \sqrt{{k^2}-8k}}{4}\leq 1.$

Tags: inequality

$$-1\leq \frac{-k \pm \sqrt{{k^2}-8k}}{4}\leq 1$$

The problem is the square root, as I don't think I can just square both sides. Any ideas?

So this actually comes from a quadratic in $$\sin{\theta}$$

Thanks.

Comment: Then move terms other than the root to the other side.

Comment: Of course you can square both sides, _as long as you understand what are you doing_ and what will happen to the inequality.

Comment: Or, regard the middle term as the solution to a certain quadratic equation depending on $k$, and find the range of this $k$ via analyzing the corresponding quadratic function.

Comment: This is the solution set of $2x^2+kx +k=0$ in $x$.

Comment: Do you mean that the two numbers (the one with "+" and the one with "-") have to be **simultaneously** in $[-1,1]$ ?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* See also the section on titles in [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959#10144) (The part entitled "Make your title your question" is especially relevant to this.)

Comment: "I don't think I can just square both sides."  Sure you can! If $-1 \le K \le 1$ then $0\le |K| \le 1$ and $0\le K^2 \le 1$.  And if you have $-a \le K \le b$ then you can do $K \le \max(a,b)$ and $K^2 \le \max(a^2, b^2)$.

Comment: Be so kind as to answer my question.

Comment: How did you get the $\pm$.  Do you mean that *both* are between $-1$ and $1$ or that one or the other might be.  $k \ge 8$ or $k\le 0$ and if *both* are between $1$ and $-1$ you will find that $k=0$.  But if you mean a solution to a quadratic must have an absolute value less than $1$ that is something else.

Comment: It means that either minus or plus has to satisfy the inequality. It comes from a quadratic in sin, hence why it is between minus one and one

Answer (score 2):

The middle term is actually the two roots $x_{\pm}$ [not necessarily distinct] for the equation
$$
2x^2 + kx + k = 0. 
$$
Let $f(x) = 2x^2 + kx + k$. Then this is an upward parabola symmetric w.r.t. the line $x = -k/4$. Note that it always passes through the point $(-1, 2)$. Then by the graph of this function, $x_{\pm } \in [-1, 1]$ iff
$$
\begin{cases}
\Delta = k^2 - 8k \geqslant 0, \\
-\dfrac k 4 \in [-1, 1], \\
f(-1) \geqslant 0, \\
f(1) \geqslant 0, 
\end{cases} \iff 
\begin{cases}
k \in (-\infty, 0] \cup [8, +\infty), \\
k \in [- 4,4] \\
2 \geqslant 0, \\
2 + 2k \geqslant 0, 
\end{cases}
$$
iff
$$
\boxed {\boldsymbol {k \in [-1, 0]}}\ .
$$

#### Update

If it means **either** one lies in the interval $[-1,1]$, then
$$
\begin{cases}
\Delta = k^2 - 8k \geqslant 0, \\
-\dfrac k 4 \geqslant -1, \\
f(1) \leqslant 0,
\end{cases}
$$
also works, and the final result is $\boldsymbol {(-\infty, 0]}$ instead.

Comment: That's the condition for **both** the expression with $+$ and the expression with $-$ to be in $[-1,1]$.  If you want **at least one**, then $k < -1$ is also allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Write it as
$$ k - 4 \le \pm \sqrt{k^2 - 8k} \le k + 4$$
Now there will be cases depending on whether $k$ is in the interval $(-\infty, -4]$, $[-4,4]$ or $[4,\infty)$.

EDIT: For example, if $k \in (-\infty, -4]$, the $\pm$ must be $-$, and
$k-4 \le -\sqrt{k^2 - 8 k} \le k+4 \le 0$ becomes
$$0 \le (k+4)^2 \le k^2-8k \le (k-4)^2$$
Expand the squares and subtract $k^2-8k$...

Comment: How does that help exactly? Sorry, I'm a noob XD